# How to catch "Pause" or restart "event" using phonegap build?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Hi I am making a JQM and PhoneGap app. I would like to catch events like "pause","restart" or resume. Do you know how to do this? I read docs, but there are no clues how to do it in javascript code for phonegap build.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [the documentation for the events](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#pause), they give a full example as well as a short example, which I'll reproduce here:

```
document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);

function onPause() {
  // Handle the pause event
}
```

Just like in normal JavaScript, you can attach to events using the `addEventListener` method on any node. In the case of PhoneGap, their device events are triggered on the `document` object.

If I understand you correctly and JQM means jQuery Mobile: In jQuery, it's possible to add handlers for arbitrary events by using:

```
$(document).on('pause', onPause);
```

(This uses the jQuery 1.7 syntax, but I believe that's a requirement for jQuery Mobile).